# Send/Receive data between 2 differant programs connected to the same Rooter (With-out internet) (JavaScript and Electron)

Tags: javascript, electron, local

I am trying to add a future called 'add monitors' to my programme where the user can display some data on an other computer (a sub programme) on the same building and be able to receive data from it (it's not a remote desktop, the 2 programms are operated by 2 differant persons, they don't have access to each-other's computer but they can send and receive data between them).More over, I want him to be able to do it with out using internet, just by using the rooter that he is connected to.

The idea is :

Main programme -> asks rooter for connected computers list -> sends back MAC adresses -> connect -> wait for response (for data)

Since I have never done such a thing and I don't realy get how requests and that stuff works I couldn't even Imagine a way to do it.

I am using Electron.

If any one has an idea or a hint for me , I would be really grateful, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to achieve this result, but you basically need a client on your pc and a server on the pc you want to control. Usually you connect the two machine trough ssh and grant acces to the desktop server. Here an interesting article: [remote desktop](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-Remote-Desktop-Connection-work). Connection is not a problem here if pc are in the same local network and you don't need to retrieve a mac address, router will do the job for you.

#### Edit

there's not a js library that makes this whole job for you, choose one of the possible way of implements needed functionalities and find library that implement that functionalities. For example RDP is a wide used protocol in this case, here a node (js) library found on the network: [RDP](https://github.com/citronneur/node-rdpjs). Be aware that different OSs need different settings, I quick read this library and this is for Windows so you need to find a way to implement the same thing on different OS.

Comment: I understand that methode, but is there any kind of JS library to do that ? Because I want the user to be able to it when ever he want, so that means it have to be an automatic process.

Comment: I think you missunderstood something .. The 2 programms should be operated by 2 different persons, it's not a remote desktop that am looking for. I don't want to open a window on the main programme.I edited my question.